# Best option to cache information in order to have a fast http response

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, caching

I am developing a web service which listens for HTTP requests. That service has to respond very fast and handle the maximum number of concurrent requests possible.

That service has one endpoint with 2 request parameters (`param1` and `param2`), which are used to validate some information and then send a response.

I have some information predefined that I will use to validate the request parameters. For example:

- I know that the `param1` is assigned to `assign1` and has the property `prop1`. `Param1` is also assigned to `assign3` which has the property `prop3`.
- And that `param2` is assigned to `assign2` and has the property `prop2`.

With that information, when I get an HTTP request, I need to validate that `param1` is assigned with `assign1` or `assign2`, otherwise, I should return an empty response.

Obviously, the idea is to avoid hard-coding it and would be nice if I could modify that information while the server is running up.

In order to achieve that, I know two existing solutions (there are probably more) :

- Use `spring boot`, and set that information in a .yml file, in order to read them through a spring bean using placeholders like `@Value(${param1})`, etc. The problem is that I will need to reload the application if I want to see the changes made in that .yml file, so technically I can not modify the cached info while the server is running up.
- Use an embedded database like `H2` and get the information for every request using a select. The problem is that I need to make a select for every request (and if I have to make any join it would increase the response time). But I could modify the info while the server is running up.

I would like to know which would be the best option to "cache" that information and let the service be very fast as every request is blocking.

I'm also using spring boot to make that service, but if you know any better web container I'm willing to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You are prematurely optimizing.

For one: “I need to process requests very fast” and “handle as many requests as possible” are sort of vague criteria for performance.

You could express your goals more clearly like so:

1. I need my service handle 99% of all requests, each hour, with a latency of 50ms or less.
2. And I need my service to be able to handle 1000 requests per second (or whatever number you need)

Then, you can begin to measure performance and optimize as necessary.

Of course caching results is a great idea and you should do it. But if you’re worried that a local database, running on the same server is going to add significant latency to your service, you may find that that is not the case.

Comment: I can confirm that for an empty / almost empty table, even on a default mysql installation on my laptop, SELECT request hardly last more than 1ms, usually around 200-400 nano seconds. With an embedded db such as H2, I guess it might even fall below 100nano seconds so It's probably quick enough to use it for your application.

Comment: You are totally right. The question here radicates in which would be the best option handling a lot of concurrent requests very fast. It is the only requirement that I have. Note: is just for learning, it is not for production or any company. 
If you would be asked about my requirement how would you proceed for example? Which technologies would you use to achieve that?

Comment: You first define your requirement. A system that can handle 1000s of requests per second is usually sufficient for 99% of use cases out there. And usually latency of 100-200ms is quite acceptable for web services. Anything in the 10-20ms would be a great feat and then you start to have more trouble because the connectivity to your service becomes a bottleneck..

Comment: But don’t start micro-optimizing. You can’t optimize what you can’t measure. Instrument, record metrics and the optimize as necessary. And set realistic performance goals!

Comment: Okay, and with your system definition (1000 requests per second and latency of 100-200ms), which would be the best "architecture"?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you want to tell me.

Comment: The best architecture depends on lots of things including exactly what your service will be doing and the tools you have at your disposal. If all your service does is validate requests based on some dynamic configuration, then probably having your service periodically update its config in the background from a database and then storing that config in memory would be great.